# count the displayed data

Tags: php, filter, count

I have a page that display the logs of student according to date, year, section and IN/OUT. My question, how to count the number of student who displayed by filtering.

screenshot:http://oi60.tinypic.com/2a5ejgg.jpg

This is the code.

```
//SET UP SQL STATEMENT
$WHERE='';
if ($year<>'0')
{
    $WHERE = " student.year =  $year ";
}

if ($section<>'0')
{
    if ($WHERE=='')
    {
        $WHERE = " student.section =  '" . $section . "'";
    }
    else
    {
        $WHERE = $WHERE . "and student.section =  '" . $section . "'";
    }
}
//SET UP SQL STATEMENT
if ($in_out<>'0')
{
    if ($WHERE=='')
    {
        $WHERE = " `log`.status_log =  '" . $in_out . "'";
    }
    else
    {
        $WHERE = $WHERE . "and `log`.status_log =  '" . $in_out . "'";
    }
}
//SET UP SQL STATEMENT
if ($datefilter<>'')
{
    if ($WHERE=='')
    {
        $WHERE = " `log`.date_log =  '" . $datefilter . "'";
    }
    else
    {
        $WHERE = $WHERE . "and `log`.date_log =  '" . $datefilter . "'";
    }
}
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;

if ($WHERE=='')
{
    //SET UP SQL STATEMENT
    $sql = "SELECT `log`.id, (student.id) as ids, student.name, 
                   student.`year`, student.section, `log`.date_log, 
                   `log`.time_log, `log`.ampm, `log`.status_log,
                   section.sec_name 
            FROM `log` 
               Inner Join student ON student.cardcode = `log`.stud_id 
               Inner Join section ON section.id = student.section 
            order by `log`.id DESC 
            limit $start,$per_page";
}
else
{//SET UP SQL STATEMENT SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalin FROM log WHERE status_log='in'
    $sql = "SELECT `log`.id, (student.id) as ids, student.name,
                   student.`year`, student.section, `log`.date_log, 
                   `log`.time_log, `log`.ampm, `log`.status_log, 
                   section.sec_name 
            FROM `log` 
               Inner Join student ON student.cardcode = `log`.stud_id 
               Inner Join section ON section.id = student.section 
            WHERE $WHERE 
            order by `log`.id DESC
            limit $start,$per_page";

}
//EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT
$result = mysql_query($sql);


//OOP ALL QUERY DATA ON LOAD AS LIST
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr style="font-size: 12px;" class="record">';
    echo '<td ><a style="text-decoration:none; color:#4F6B72" href="studentlog.php?id='.$row['ids'].'"</a>' .$row['name']. '</td>';
    if ($row['year']=='1')
    { echo '<td>&nbsp;1st</td>';}
    else if ($row['year']=='2')
    { echo '<td>&nbsp;2nd</td>';}
    else if ($row['year']=='3')
    { echo '<td>&nbsp;3rd</td>';}
    else if ($row['year']=='4')
    { echo '<td>&nbsp;4th</td>';}
    echo '<td >'. $row['sec_name'].  '</td>';
    echo '<td >'. $row['status_log'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['date_log'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['time_log'] . ' ' . $row['ampm']   .'</td>';
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. We're programmers, not prophets.

Comment: I downwoted this because you havent shared any code to look at. Share the relevant code you want to filter.

Comment: sir good day i have been posted the code

Comment: how to count? well... use `count()`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have executed the query you can us `mysql_num_rows()` which tells you the actual number of row return by the query

So

```
//EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT 
$result = mysql_query($sql);        

$rows_returned = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

> As it seems obvious you are just learning PHP and MYSQL can I suggest that you do not use the `mysql_` extension!
>
> Instead learn `mysqli_` or `PDO` [see this document for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: thankyou sir.but sir I have question how to count the displayed data sir?

Comment: Go ahead I am listening

Comment: Do you mean how to count the actual lines of data you show on the page? Or how to count all the possible rows that match the filter on the database

Comment: count the student id who have in and out value from data

Comment: sir can you give me your email i will send you the screenshot of my project

Comment: this is the image of my project   http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2a5ejgg&s=8#.VcnLQighyuI

Comment: Do you mean that you want to count the total number of rows that the query will contain so you can control the pagination?

Comment: yes sir, but I found now the solution thank you so much sir  for your response